# Android Firebase - add authenticated user into database

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

Ok, so I am building xamarin.android applicationon in Visual Studio and there is quite a lot of questions of this type, but I really didn't find anything regarding xamarin.android, everything is Java based. I tried following those tutorials and answers but there was always something missing or not working on Xamarin android.

I have made authentication and it works great, no problems there. And i tried storing user information (info that user types in while registering) into database. It kind of worked, but with one problem. Here is code:

```
  public void OnComplete(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsSuccessful)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Successful", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app).CurrentUser;
            id = user.Uid;
            CreateUser();

            buttonSignIn.PerformClick();
            progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
        else
        {
     //something
        }
    }
```

And here is `CreateUser()` method:

```
  private void CreateUser ()
    {
        Account user = new Account();
        user.uid = id;
        user.name = signup_inputName;
        user.lastName = signup_inputLastName;
        user.email = signup_inputEmail;
        user.phone = signup_inputPhoneNumber;

        var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);
        var item = firebase.Child("users").PostAsync<Account>(user);

    }
```

Here is Account class code:

```
public class Account
{
    public string uid      { get; set; }
    public string name     { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email    { get; set; }
    public string phone    { get; set; }

}
```

This code stores user information under `"users"` node in database. But there is one more node under `"user"` with some random value and below are information about user (including `uid`). Here is output:

```
- Users   
      -LBGFtYFTfD3l1hmwHVn
          email:  "testuser@test.com"
          lastName:"peric"
          name:  "pero"
          phone: "12321"
          uid: "18puc5CzSZfzbdflzekzNCHGHR62"
```

So, my question is, shouldn't this random value below `"users"` node be `uid`? If yes, how to set it that way?
I tried with this:

```
Account user = new Account();
            user.uid = id;
            user.name = signup_inputName;
            user.lastName = signup_inputLastName;
            user.email = signup_inputEmail;
            user.phone = signup_inputPhoneNumber;

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").Child(uid).SetValue(user)
```

But that didn't work, I was getting this error:

```
Firebase No properties to serialize found on class
```

Even though I have set public getters and setters in users class.

I need to get that user info and show it on some places in my app, but I just can't get it to work. This is my first time using Firebase and I am used to SQL database so this is really confusing to me. Also, there is very little information online about xamarin.android and firebase, plus I am actually new to programming in general. Any help would be appreciate. This is my last try before switching to SQL online database.

Comment: Please show us the source code for the `Account` class.

Comment: Hello. I added Account class code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `PostAsync` the client creates a new child node under the location that you call it on. This is similar to the HTTP `POST` verb, and the `push()` method in most other Firebase SDKs.

To write data to a location that you exactly specify, use `PutAsync`:

```
var item = firebase.Child("users").Child(uid).PutAsync<Account>(user);
```

See the [example from the Readme of Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin/blob/master/README.md#saving-data).

Comment: Well, I was trying it this way (specifying two child nodes) and I always got error, assumed it won't work and tried something else. Didn't know I should be using Xamarin.Database.Query. After that, it worked. And .PutAsync did the trick. Thank you very much sir. 

I will get on with reading provided link, hope I will be able to retrieve that that later on.